# c++ - template Linked List and how to write the class correctly (insertInFront error)

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I'm trying to write the function insertInFront but i having trouble.
How can I implement this function correctly?

And I'd be happy to explain what it means when I have & after the name as in this example:

```
ListNode(const NODETYPE &)
```

Does that mean I'm getting a NODETYPE address in the function?

List.h:

```
template<class NODETYPE> 
class List {

ListNode<NODETYPE> *firstPtr;
ListNode<NODETYPE> *lastPtr;

ListNode <NODETYPE> *getNewNode(const NODETYPE &);

public: 
List();
~List();
void insertAtFront(const NODETYPE &);
void insertAtBack(const NODETYPE &);
void removeFromFront(NODETYPE &);
void removeFromBack(NODETYPE &);
bool isEmpty()const;
void print()const;
}; 

template<class NODETYPE>
void List<NODETYPE>::insertAtFront(const NODETYPE &) {
firstPtr = data;
lastPtr = nextPtr; 
}
```

ListNode.h:

```
template<class NODETYPE>
class ListNode {
friend class List<NODETYPE>;
private: 
NODETYPE data; 
ListNode<NODETYPE> *nextPtr; 

public: 
ListNode(const NODETYPE &);
NODETYPE getDate()const; 
};
```

thank's.

Comment: No that means you get a "value" of type NODETYPE passed and have to create a new ListNode of type NODETYPE. This sounds like homework, share what you have got so far.

Comment: & means reference at this context. You should read about references, and passing parameters into functions by value and by reference